# Literature on group cohomology of (Z/nZ)* with coefficients in Z/nZ

Tags: cyclic-groups, group-cohomology

The multiplication of the default ring structure gives a group action of $(\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z)^*$ on $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$:
$$(\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z)^* \oplus \mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z \ni (a, m) \mapsto a \cdot m \in \mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$$

Therefore, we have a first cohomology group $H^1((\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z)^*, \mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z)$.

After some calculating, which took about a week of spare time, I got to the following result:
$$ \#H^1((\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z)^*, \mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z) = \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{if}\ 2 \nmid n \\
    2^{\{\text{prime factors of n}\} - 1} & \text{if}\ 2 \mid n, 4 \nmid n \\
    2^{\{\text{prime factors of n}\}} & \text{if}\ 4 \mid n
\end{cases}. $$

Is this correct?

I do not think that I am the first to have done this, but in my initial search, I was not really able to find any literature on it. Is there any literature on $H^1((\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z)^*, \mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z)$? Somewhere where I could have looked up this result?

Comment: Notice that $(\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z})^*$ is the Galois group of the extension $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbf{Q}$ and $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z} = \mu_n$ is the group of $n$-th roots of unity, so you might be able to relate your results to standard results results in Galois cohomology found for example in Poonen's Rational points on varieties Prop.1.5.13. (There are probably better resources, maybe take a look at Serre's book on Galois cohomology).

Comment: Hahahaha. This is actually derived from exercise 4.2 in Poonen! So this problem does indeed come from the action of the galois group on the nth roots of unity. But thank you! I already forgot that I read Proposition 1.5.13.

Comment: Nice, I didn't even think about it in terms of twists, haven't even read that far, so thank you, too!